# Acumatica and Automation Notifications and how to get them to show up in an opportunity activity tab

Tags: acumatica

We are looking into automation notifications and here is our use case:

We will be automating the creation of opportunities through process screens. And then after an opportunity is created, we want to have the system automatically send the contact an email. Is the best way to achieve this through automation notifications? Assuming yes, I have that under control as to how to set that up.

However, if that is the best way, i'm noticing that the notification is not showing up under the activity for the opportunity which is a bit problematic. Is it supposed to? And if not, then where are you to see that a notification was sent out to the contact? And is there any other workaround so that it shows up in the Activity tab?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with 'Automation Notification' so I am not sure whether it is by-design that it does not add an Activity.

Some workarounds could be the following:

1. Do not use 'Automation Notification' but implement everything in a Graph Extension. This would include sending the email and adding an Activity. Perhaps you could do this in Row Persisted. Of course you need to check that it is a new record.
2. Use Business Events rather than 'Automation Notification' and perhaps add your own Push Notification to handle all the logic of sending the email and adding an Activity. This blog posts explains the process of adding a custom Push Notification https://www.acumatica.com/blog/push-notifications-implementing-custom-destination-type/